# How to make list comprehensions more readable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list, list-comprehension

I have this bit of code below, and i think it's kinda hard to understand if you are new to python.

How would i go about making it more readable to a group of newcomers to python (students)

```
def right_inwrongplace(userGuess, number):
    correct_places = [True if v == number[i] else False for i, v in enumerate(userGuess)]
    g = [v for  i, v in enumerate(userGuess) if not correct_places[i]]
    n = [v for  i, v in enumerate(number) if not correct_places[i]]
    return len([i for i in g if i in n])
```

Comment: What a problem to write usual loops?

Comment: Try putting `v == number[i]` instead of `True if v == number[i] else False`

Comment: you can use `index` and `value` instead of `i` and `v` to make it more explicit (other letters too)

Comment: Beginners do *not* understand "pythonic" in-place list creation loops.  It can be seen often on SO - someone answers a python question with a cryptic in-place list creation, then the OP responds. "Huh?!".  Create the lists long-hand.  Also as @OferSadan points out, use more meaningful variable names - `i` for a numeric iterator is fine, but `v`, `g` and `n` aren't.  Where are the code comments too?

Comment: @Kingsley I will add, people often mistakenly think turning everything into a *list comprehension* is what pythonic means, but that is not true. If something is unreadable, it isn't pythonic! That is one of the core values in python! Readability counts! now, simple mapping/filtering operations are *often* pythonically expressed as list comprehensions, but if it becomes unwieldy, then the entire purpose of that language construct is subverted.

Comment: this is a better fit for [codereview.se]. In any case, there are many improvements you could make here. Use `zip` to iterate over two sequences in corresponding pairs, don't use indices (see answer below). craft your boolean expressions idiomatically, `True if something == something_else else False` is a wordy way of saying `something == something_else`. And, the simplest bust most effective: use more meaningful variable names, and factor out common logic into functions with meaningful names.

Comment: if you post on Code Review please read the help center pages like [_How do I ask a good question?_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) - in its current form this post would be considered off-topic because there is little context about what the code does and how the function is used, plus the title is about CR goals instead of describing what the code does

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few improvements:

- `True if x else False` is simply `bool(x)` or, as you are doing a comparison already, just that expression, i.e. `v == number[i]`.
- Since you are accessing the number by positional index you can just `zip` the two sequences.

So for the first you'd get:

```
correct_places = [x == y for x, y in zip(userGuess, number)]
```

The same argument with `zip` applies to the following two comprehensions (you can again iterate over the original string):

```
g = [x for x, y in zip(userGuess, number) if x != y]
n = [y for x, y in zip(userGuess, number) if x != y]
```

Given that this is basically the same comprehension two times, and that we don't need `correct_places` anymore we can instead do the following:

```
g, n = zip(*[(x, y) for x, y in zip(userGuess, number) if x != y])
```

Then you can `sum` instead of `len`:

```
return sum(x in n for x in g)
```

So basically you can use the following code:

```
g, n  = zip(*(xy for xy in zip(userGuess, num) if xy[0] != xy[1])
return sum(x in n for x in g)
```

Comment: `g, n = zip(*[...])` is cute, but very cryptic. I do not consider it an improvement. However, using `zip` to iterate over two in corresponding pairs *is* good.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That's true, so maybe better to stay with the two separate comprehensions :-) Once you recognize that `zip(*[...])` basically transposes the given sequence, it becomes a bit clearer (in some cases at least). I use it for that purpose from time to time, but together with a comprehension it seems a bit heavy. But `transposed = zip(*sequence)` is readable I find.

Comment: Look, my criteria is "if a competent programmer in another language who isn't very familiar with python will have a hard time understanding it, it is't readable". sure, you can argue there are certain idioms that become common to a language, I'm just not sure `transposed = zip(*sequence)` is one of them. I think this is a great example of how this question is too opinion-based, honestly, it is a better fit for CodeReview